# Can' get with libxml2.h,file not found, XMPP framework

Tags: xmpp, ios8, xcode6, libxml2, xmppframework

For the last three days I am trying to import XMPP framework and constantly getting this error:`"<libxml/tree.h> file not found"` in `DDXMLNode.h`. I copied suggested files to project, created groups, imported necessary libraries,add a flag `-lxml2`(I tried to add it to project or to target or to them both-nothing helps).I also tried to specify `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` in header search path,library search path,users search paths of target,project or in them both - again nothing. I looked at sample project, it works. But they don't specify `other linker flags` at all. They do header search paths of project and target(and everything is fine). So nothing helps, while sample project with same settings works. Any suggestions?

Additional info: I use xcode 6,target is iOS8, in target's build settings I use -all_load flag for some other sdk's(just in case this matters)

Comment: Am getting same issue! have u solved above issue @efimovD

Comment: I can't remember the actual way I did this, but I definetely used something like libxml/libxml.h. If I figure out more, I will notify you.@sabir

Comment: So? Did you solve the problem?? @efimovD

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. This [link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS) helped me out. If you follow instructions step by step, I think it will solve the problem.

Steps can be summarised as:
Step 1. Make sure you link CFNetwork framework and Security framework

Step 2. Goto Projects -> Build Settings and add “/usr/include/libxml2” to Header search path 
[image]
Step 3. Also add “-lxml2” to Other linker flags[image]
Step 4. Add following folders from XMPPFramework to your project:
Authentication, Core, Categories, Utilities, Vendor 
[image]